# Heap has been corrupted after a certain size malloc In C

Tags: c, heap-memory, heap-corruption

Im trying to write a very simple compressor in C and I ran into the error "Heap has been corrupted" in my code. I looked into it, and the error seems to come because of this line:

```
ptr = (char*)malloc(count * sizeof(char));
```

when i change the size from count to 1000 it works, and i tried debugging and seeing if there is a difference somewhere but i couldnt find it, i understand there might be somekind of an overflow but i dont understand why and whats the solution instead of just writing a big number to fix it

this is my code for now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

errno_t err;
int count =0;

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

struct node* newNode(int data) {
        struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        node->data = data;

        node->left = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;
        return (node);
    };

int* frequency(char* str) {

    FILE* fptr;
    err = fopen_s(&fptr, str, "r");
    if (err != 0)
    {
        printf("The file wasn't opened\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    int* ptr;
    ptr = (int*)malloc(95 * sizeof(int));

    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
        exit(0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 95; i++) {
        *(ptr + i) = 0;
    }
    char ch;
    int index;

    while ((ch = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF) {
        index = (int)ch - 32;
        (*(ptr+index))++;
    }

    err = fclose(fptr);
    if (err != 0)
    {
        printf("The file wasn't closed\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 95; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *(ptr+i));
    }
    return ptr;
}

void* letFrequency(int* occLet) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 95; i++) // counts how many actually occur 
    {
        if (*(occLet+i) > 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    int* ptr;
    ptr = (char*)malloc(count * sizeof(char));
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
        exit(0);
    }

    int max = 0;
    int placement = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 95; i++) {
            if (*(occLet+i) >= max)
            {
                max = *(occLet+i);
                placement = i;
            }
        }
        *(ptr+j) = (char)(placement + 32);
        printf("%c", *(ptr +j));
        *(occLet+placement) = 0;
        max = 1;
    }
    return ptr;
}

void binaryMap(char* letFrq) {
    struct node* rootzero = newNode(1);
    struct node* rootone = newNode(0);

    int leaveszero = 0;
    int leavesone = 0;

    if (count % 2 == 0) {
        leavesone = count / 2;
        leaveszero = count / 2;
    }
    else
    {
        leavesone = count / 2;
        leaveszero = count / 2 + 1;
        printf("%d", leaveszero);
    }

}


int main() {
    char str[70];
    printf("Enter the name of the text file you want to compress: ");
    scanf_s("%s", str, sizeof(str));
    int* ptrFr;
    char* ptrLetFr;
    ptrFr = frequency(str);
    ptrLetFr = letFrequency(ptrFr);
    free(ptrFr);
    binaryMap(ptrLetFr);
}
```

Comment: why ```int*ptr``` not ```char*ptr```?

Comment: In C do not cast the return of `malloc()` is is a `void*` so unnecessary.  `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition - so that is unnecessary too.  But `ptr = malloc( count * sizeof(*ptr) ) ;` is a good idea since it allows the type of `prt` to change minimal maintenance - avoiding type errors.

Comment: @MohamedAkram has probably spotted it, and my suggestion would have avoided it.

Comment: And the file you read only contains characters with a value > 32 and < 115?

Comment: yes especially because ey is using ```*(ptr+j)``` which will jump 4 bytes instead of 1 byte because it is ```int*```

Comment: For better readbility you should rather use `x[y]` instead of `*(x + y)`. That's the idiomatic way. And you should replace the magic value 95 with a constant of with a macro (e.g `#define MAX_WHATEVER 95`).

Comment: @MohamedAkram thank you! i didnt even notice that, it solved the issue :)

Comment: Check the value of `index` is in range before doing `(*(ptr+index))++;`. `index` will have a negative value when a newline is read, for example.

Comment: @RonaMakarona *```:)```*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines;

```c
    int* ptr;
    ptr = (char*)malloc( count * sizeof(char));
```

are clearly erroneous.  If you intended `count` integers, then `sizeof(char)` will allocate too small a block.  I suggest as a *habit*:

- Do not cast `void*` - just assign it.
- Use `sizeof` *the object pointed to*, not an explicit type.
- Do not leave dangling pointers unnecessary.

To that end:

```c
    int* ptr = malloc(count * sizeof(*ptr) ) ;
```

Or if it were _intended to be `char*` then:

```
    char* ptr = malloc(count * sizeof(*ptr) ) ;
```

Note how minimal the change is - you don't have to correct  it three different places.

Comment: It should be a char* , but thank you for the tips! the code works :)